# video chroma keyed background into Skype

Tags: live, chromakey

I speak to my sons via Skype (for Win 10).  I have a new green screen, and would like to surprise them by pretending to be on a beach when we next talk.

Zoom can chroma key in a beach with waving palm tree and waves.  Skype just allows static images.

Is there a free package that would make it easy to get something like Zoom's functionality in Skype?  I'd be particularly pleased for a link to step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no plugin I never heard of, the only way you could do this is by feeding an already keyed signal into skype. You could try researching if realtime keying can be emulated on a virtual webcam, otherwise you would either have to stick with zoom or buy a live-keyer like the ones from black-magic (though they are very very expensive)

Comment: thanks - it looks like OBS might be what I need: https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2017/12/19/improving-your-video-meetings-on-skype-with-green-screens

Comment: OBS, with its virtual cam (https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949), work